# Selection of Multivalue as well as NULL values in parameter which has null values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

So this is bit confusing. I already have a stored procedure. I have report which has 5 to 6 parameters. I want it to run the report in such a way that you should be able to select multiple values in the drop down and also keep it optional(not select any values). Other thing is that my parameter value also has NULL values which I have replaced it with NA. I tried using Default Value in the Parameter properties for some selection it works and for some selection it does not. I am still an intermediate person working on SSRS. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you are asking for a solution to the code you (or someone else) wrote, you might want to post what you have already so people can help you fix or enhance it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have created a function and used that function in stored procedure to make that stored procedure as multi value selection.

In your function Whichever variable has varchar or any string data type make their size to MAX like varchar(max) and also do the same thing in Stored procedure for parameter.

Reason behind this one:  When you provide the data type as varchar(255) it will just take a value for 255 character and if your value character is exceeding that limit then it will truncate the data which is exceeding that limit. And you are making them multi select so probably you need to make them as varchar(max).

Also make the size as Max in stored procedure for parameter.

Note:  Varchar(Max) is just an example. You can provide max to any string data type that you have used in function and stored procedure.

Let me know if it works..

Comment: Correct. I have created a function which will take value from parameter and split them which Comma ',', so that each value is separated as one value.

Comment: can you share your code for function and stored procedure?

Comment: Sure... But for some reason this comment box asking for some formatting of my code

Comment: Is there anyone that can help to solve my issue? Any type of help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you change the Value nvarchar(100) to Value nvarchar(max) in function? and check that its working or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PIMSelect_AJ_Test] 

@network nvarchar(MAX),
--@provider nvarchar(MAX),
--@affiltype varchar(MAX),
--@npi varchar(MAX),
--@tin varchar(MAX),
--@inprovtype varchar (MAX),
@SLG nvarchar(MAX),
@county nvarchar(MAX),
@zip nvarchar(Max),
@specCode nvarchar(Max),
@affiltype nvarchar(Max),
@contract nvarchar(Max)

    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

select * from ( 
    select 
distinct    P1.Provid as PIMProviderID,
            P.NetworkName,
            --COALESCE(pa.affiltype, 'NA') as affiliationtype,
            PP1.planprovid as ProviderPlanProvID,
            p1.lastname as ProviderLastName,
            p1.Firstname as ProviderFirstName,
            P1.Profdesig as ProviderTitle,
            p1.intprovtype as ProviderIntProvType,
            COALESCE(NULLIF(P1.Provtype, ''), 'NA') as ProviderProvType,
            XP1.Description as ProviderTypeDescription,
            COALESCE(ps1.specialtycode, 'NA') as ProviderSpecialtyCode,
            ps1.DirectorySpec as ProviderSpecialityDescription,
            ps1.spectype as ProviderSpecType,
            p1.CredType as ProviderCredType,
            p1.phyaddress1 as ProviderPhyAddress1,
            p1.phyaddress2 as ProviderPhyAddress2,
            p1.phycity as ProviderPhyCity,
            p1.phystate as ProviderPhyState,
            p1.phyzipcode as ProviderPhyZipCode,
            p1.phycounty as ProviderPhyCounty,
            p1.address1 as ProviderMailingAddress1,
            p1.address2 as ProviderMailingAddress2,
            p1.city as ProviderMailingCity,
            p1.state as ProviderMailingState,
            p1.Zipcode as ProviderMailingZip,
            p1.county as ProviderMailingCounty,
            COALESCE(NULLIF(p1.TIN, ''),'0') as ProviderTIN,
            COALESCE(NULLIF(p1.NPI, ''),'0') as ProviderNPI,


            pa.Affiltype as AffilType,
            p.provid as AffilPIMProviderID,
            PP.planprovid as AffiliationPlanProvID,
            p.Lastname as AffilLastName,
            p.Firstname as AffilFirstName,
            COALESCE(p.intprovtype, 'NA') as AffilIntProvType,
            XP.Description as AffiliationTypeDescription,
            ps.specialtycode as AffilSpecialtyCode,
            ps.spectype as AffilSpecType,
            ps.directoryspec as AffilSpecialtyDescription,
            PA.IntDirLocation as AffilDirLocation,
            p.phyaddress1 as AffilPhyAddress1,
            p.phyaddress2 as AffilPhyAddress2,
            p.phycity as AffilPhyCity,
            p.phystate as AffilPhyState,
            COALESCE(NULLIF(p.phyzipcode, ''), 'NA') as AffilPhyZipCode,
            COALESCE(NULLIF(p.phycounty, ''), 'NA') as AffilPhyCounty,
            p.address1 as AffilMailingAddress1,
            p.address2 as AffilMailingAddress2,
            p.city as AffilMailingCity,
            p.state as AffilMailingState,
            p.Zipcode as AffilMailingZip,
            p.county as AffilMailingCounty,
            COALESCE(NULLIF(p.TIN,  ''),'0') as AffilTIN,
            COALESCE(NULLIF(p.NPI, ''),'0') as AffilNPI,
            COALESCE(CI.contractid, 'NA') as AffilContractID,
            COALESCE(C.description, 'NA') as AffilContractDesc


     from ProviderManager.dbo.Provider p
     left join ProviderManager.dbo.XProviderTypes XP on P.Provtype = XP.[Provider Type_ID]
     left join ProviderManager.dbo.planprovinfo PP on P.Provid = PP.provid
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.provspecialty ps on ps.provid = p.Provid
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.Affiliation pa on pa.affilid= p.Provid
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.provider p1 on p1.provid = pa.provid
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.CredApproval CA on P1.NPI = CA.NPI
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.planprovinfo PP1 on P1.Provid = PP1.provid
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.provspecialty ps1 on p1.Provid = ps1.provid
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.XProviderTypes XP1 on P1.Provtype = XP1.[Provider Type_ID]
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.contractinfo CI on P1.Provid = CI.provid and P.intprovtype = 'Group' and P.Provid = CI.affilid
    left join ProviderManager.dbo.Contract C on CI.contractid 
               COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = C.contractid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) cte
    WHERE  
    cte.ProviderIntProvType IN ('Facility', 'Physician')
    and (cte.NetworkName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@network, ',')))
    and (cte.AffilPIMProviderID IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@SLG, ',')))
    and (cte.AffilPhyCounty COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@county, ','))OR (@county = 'NA'))
    and (cte.Affilphyzipcode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@zip, ',')) OR (@zip = 'NA'))
    and (cte.ProviderSpecialtyCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@specCode, ',')))
    and (cte.ProviderProvType COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@affiltype, ',')))
    and (cte.AffilContractID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@contract, ',')))
    --and (cte.providerNPI COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@npi,','))) 
    --and (cte.providerTIN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select Value from VIB_Extracts.dbo.FnSplit(@TIN,',')))
    Order by Cte.ProviderLastName
```

Comment: Can some one help me out with this? I can provide all the necessary information you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
    USE [VIB_Extracts]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[FnSplit]    Script Date: 4/29/2017 9:59:16 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(MAX),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(

Id int identity(1,1),
Value nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN
While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
Begin 
Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
Select
Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
End 

Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))
Return
END
```